# IRC client with sound options for each channel separately

Tags: irc

I am searching for an IRC client with sound options for each channel separately.

As an example what I want:

- Channel `#example` on `irc.example` (sound effect for any message from anybody, and when my name is mentioned), and
- channel `#example2` on `irc.example` (no sounds except if my name is mentioned).

My coding skills are very limited so I can't script it myself. Anyone got an idea?
Jabber would be OK too.